# Die Anschovis sind gestorben – hat die irgendjemand gekannt?

Tags: spelling, history, loanword, reformed-orthography

Die letzte leichte Revision der deutschen Rechtschreibregeln vom Juni 2017 hat einiger der folgenden eingedeutschten Begriffe aus dem Wörterverzeichnis gestrichen, die ich in der genannten Schreibweise noch nie gesehen habe, erwähnt aber, dass »sie zum Teil seit Jahrzehnten in den Wörterbüchern standen(*)«.

Hat irgendjemand diese Schreibweisen tatsächlich irgendwann verwendet? Ich sehe diese Schreibweisen z. T. zum ersten Mal und hätte jede einzelne als Rechtschreibfehler betrachtet.

Es geht um die folgenden Worte bzw. Schreibweisen:

> - *<s>Anschovis</s>*, richtig *Anchovis*, eine Sardellenart
> - *<s>Frotté</s>*, richtig *Frottee*, Handtuchstoff
> - *<s>Komplice</s>*, richtig *Komplize*, ein Mittäter
> - *<s>Majonäse</s>*, richtig *Mayonnaise*
> - *<s>Wandalismus</s>*, richtig *Vandalismus*, nach einem germanischem Volksstamm, den *Vandalen* oder
> - *<s>Ketschup</s>*, richtig *Ketchup*

Der Duden kennt nach Nachschau (noch) *Anschovis*, *Frotté* und *Ketschup* ((*) das, laut Duden interessanterweise erst mit der letzen RSR 1996 ausdrücklich **erlaubt** wurde und nun wieder verschwindet).

Comment: Gehört nicht zur Frage, daher Kommentar: Erstaunlich finde ich, dass hier der RSR genau den umgekehrten Weg geht wie bei den unsäglichen *Spagetti*, also eine naiv eingedeutschte Schreibweise verbietet statt zulässt.

Comment: Ich meine mich dumpf erinnern zu können, *Wandalismus* und *Ketschup* in älteren Büchern schon mal gesehen zu haben, kann aber keine Details bieten.

Comment: Der [Komplice](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=109594) war ganz lange richtig und ist bei der Rechtschreibreform nur wiederbelebt worden.

Comment: Welche der jeweiligen varianten empfindest du als falsch? Ich empfinde jeweils die erstgenannte Variante als kompletten Blödsinn und habe bis auf "Majonäse", welche ihrerzeit durch die Presse ging, keine der Varianten je so in freier Wildbahn gesehen.

Comment: @Polygnome Jeweils die erste natürlich (deshalb steht bei der zweiten auch "richtig" ;) . Und seit gestern darf ich das auch ;)

Comment: Nur Wanndahlen und Schowinisten schreiben 'Anschovis'. Richtig deutsch ist Annschohwies.

Comment: Gehört nich zur Frage, aber sollte es nicht "es geht um die folgenden Wörter.."  (statt Worte) heißen?? Die Wörter hier haben ja keine Beziehung zueinander.

Comment: Majonäse, Anschovis, Wandalismus und Ketschup, wären (in dieser Reihenfolge) imho sinnvolle Eindeutschungen gewesen, weil sie die Schreibweise an die Aussprache anpassen.

Comment: Dass die Schreibweisen nicht angenommen wurden, war sicher ein Grund, warum man sie wieder entfernt hat. Nichts Überraschendes hier.

Comment: Also, Ketschup entspricht nicht meiner Aussprache . Wenn schon phonetisch, dann richtig!

Comment: @tofro Erstaunlich ist das eigentlich nicht.
Es gibt ja schon seit Jahren einen Rückbau der RSR,
der allerdings aus politischen Gründen nicht "Rückbau" heißen darf,
und darum unter "Weiterentwicklung" firmiert.

Answer (score 7):

Majonäse habe ich schon gesehen und ich würde sogar Majo anstell von Mayo schreiben, obwohl ich nur Mayonnaise für das vollständige Wort verwenden würde.

Das hier sind echte Fotos und die Produkte können in normalen Supermärkten hier in NRW erworben werden.
[Beweis 1](http://www.supermarktcheck.de/img/product/picture/large_da3e0ae31fd266743a28ca28e7973603.jpg)
[Beweis 2](http://www.supermarktcheck.de/img/product/picture/large_6b61cb95e15aa0175f426dd38a5abf1f.jpg)

Der Rest sieht für mich grausam aus :D

Answer (score 5):

Zumindest zu den Lebensmitteln habe ich Bilder gefunden, die die nun geächteten Schreibweisen belegen:

[image: Anschovis]
[image: Majonäse]
[image: Ketschup]

Comment: Danke. Neue Variante, die *Anschovies* mit "ie" - Die war vom alten Wörterverzeichnis aber **nicht** sanktioniert und wäre auch vor dem gestrigen Tag falsch gewesen ;)

Comment: Ich kenne das Buch *Schockoeis mit Ketschup* nicht, aber den Einband nach zu urteilen scheint es ein Krimi oder Mystery für Kinder zu sein. Ich denke, dass Ketchup hier vielleicht sogar absichtlich *falsch* geschrieben worde und die Schreibweise mit dem beworbenem Geheimnis im zusammenhang steht 

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda: Das Buch stammt vom österreichischen Kinderbuchautoren Thomas Brezina und ist der Band 11 der 26-teiligen Serie »Pssst! Unser Geheimnis«. Die Zielgruppe sind Mädchen ab acht Jahren, das Buch wurde bereits in sechs Sprachen übersetzt (Bücher von Brezina sind vor allem in China sehr beliebt). In anderen Sprachen wird das Wort im Titel sehr wohl ohne s geschrieben, z.B. brasilianisches Portugiesisch: »Chocolate Com Ketchup«. Wenn das s im Wort dramaturgisch wichtig wäre, müsste es auch in anderen Sprachen vorhanden sein.

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Thomas Brezina ist ein international höchst erfolgreicher Autor. Er hat bereits mehr als 550 Bücher geschrieben und davon 40 Millionen Exemplare verkauft, die in 35 Sprachen übersetzt wurden. In China ist seine Serie »Ein Fall für dich und das Tiger-Team« bekannter als Harry Potter. Es ist daher kaum anzunehmen, dass er eine Handlung schreibt, die darauf beruht, dass ein Wort in einer ganz bestimmten Sprache eine besondere Schreibweise aufweist.